# How to install unzip command in Codeanywhere IDE terminal Environment

Tags: using, codeanywhere

I'm trying to unzip a file on Codeanywhere IDE terminal, but the error says it does not have an unzip command. How do I install unzip command?

```
codeany@8e9ca30a558a:/workspaces/FlaskProjt$ unzip gh-pages.zip   
bash: unzip: command not found
codeany@8e9ca30a558a:/workspaces/FlaskProjt$ ^C
codeany@8e9ca30a558a:/workspaces/FlaskProjt$ su -
Password: 
codeany@8e9ca30a558a:/workspaces/FlaskProjt$ ^C
codeany@8e9ca30a558a:/workspaces/FlaskProjt$ apt-get install sudo
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
codeany@8e9ca30a558a:/workspaces/FlaskProjt$ su -
Password:
```